# Trouble Accessing FetchEvent in Hono JS Context on Cloudflare Workers

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-r2, hono

I'm developing a Cloudflare Workers application using Hono JS and encountering an issue where I'm unable to access `FetchEvent` within the Hono context. The application works fine with itty router and the default Cloudflare worker setup, but with Hono, I'm facing difficulties.

Here's a snippet of my `index.js`:

```
const app = new Hono();

app.get('/backgroundsounds', async (c) => {
    const event = c.event
    console.log("Event is", event);
    return await handleBackgroundSoundsGetAll(c);
});

export default app;
```

And here is my `handleBackgroundSoundsGetAll` function:

```
    export const handleBackgroundSoundsGetAll = async (c) => {
    const { MY_BUCKET } = c.env;

    const request = c.req; // Access the request from the Hono context
    const cacheUrl = new URL(request.url);

    const cacheKey = new Request(cacheUrl.toString(), { method: 'GET' });
    const cache = caches.default;
    const fileName = "backgroundsounds.json";

    console.log("Checking cache for key", cacheKey);
    let response = await cache.match(cacheKey);
    console.log("Cache match result", response);

    // Access R2 bucket from environment bindings
    const backgroundSoundsJson = c.env.MY_BUCKET.get(fileName);
    console.log("Fetching object and ETag from R2 bucket in the background");

    if (response) {
        console.log("Cache hit, serving response");
        if (c.event) {
            c.event.waitUntil(...)
        }
        return response;
    } else {
        // Additional handling for cache miss
    }
};
```

I'm getting an error saying `This context has no FetchEvent`. I'm not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong. The same logic works when I use itty router or the standard Cloudflare worker setup.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Hono on Cloudflare Workers or can point out what might be going wrong with my implementation?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're using [Module Workers](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/reference/migrate-to-module-workers/) (`export default`), rather than Service Workers, so there is no more `addEventListener` or events.

You will have `c.req`, `c.env` and `c.executionCtx` instead.

`c.req` is a `Request` object equivalent to `event.request`.

`c.env` contains your bindings, which are no-longer globals but instead on the `env` object.

`c.executionCtx` contains `waitUntil()` and `passThroughOnException()` which are equivalent to the methods that would have been on the `event` object.

Take a look at Hono's [Cloudflare Workers guide](https://hono.dev/getting-started/cloudflare-workers) and the [Context API reference](https://hono.dev/api/context).